# How can I remove a list element from a list which is inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have following dictionary of lists:-

```
myDict = {"A": [4, 8, 10, 9], "B": [6, 9, 10]}
```

I want to remove value 10 from the list that corresponds to key 'A' of myDict.

Please suggest how can I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 4):

```
myDict['A'].remove(10)
```

because the list is modified in place

Answer (score 0):

You can access your list as follows:

```
myDict['A']
[4, 8, 10, 9]
```

then remove it or whatever you need to do with the list:

```
mydict['A'].remove(10)
```